# Padding list within lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list:

```
list = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1, 6}, {1, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2}};
```

How can the sub-lists be padded to the length of the longest sub-list (in this case 3), with the last value of the sub-list? The expected result is

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 6}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2}}

Comment: Aaand everyone posted basically the same answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ list], "Fixed"] & /@ list
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 6}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1,
>      3, 2}}

Comment: `PadRight[#, 3, "Fixed"] & /@ {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}}` fails

Comment: thank you @corey979. changed `3` to `Max@Length@list`

Comment: very elegant, cheers

Answer (score 12):

```
With[{n = Max[Length /@ list]}, PadRight[#, n, Last @ #] & /@ list]
```

Comment: Unlike the other answers, this version avoids needlessly computing `Max[Length /@ list]` over and over again.

Answer (score 9):

```
PadRight[list, Automatic, list[[All, {-1}]]]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 6}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1,
>      3, 2}}

The 3rd argument can also be `Take[list, All, -1]`.

Comment: Best answer, IMHO. I just knew there was this kind of elegant approach.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear[pad]
pad = Function[list,
   PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ list], Last@#] & /@ list
   ];
pad@{{1}, {1}, {1}, {1, 6}, {1, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Map[Function[sl, PadRight[sl, Max[Length /@ list], Last@sl]], list]
```

As MarcoB rightly noted, the original version of the answer had a couple of missing brackets and did not correctly inject the arguments into `Function` which has `HoldAll` attribute. This answer is of course very similar to many others.

Comment: I think it needs some adjustments

Comment: @MarcoB thanks, fixed. I was hoping to avoid repeated evaluation of `Length/@list`, but the evaluation sequence foiled me.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way:

```
With[{size = Max@(Length /@ list)}, 
 Join[#, ConstantArray[Last@#, size - Length@#]] & /@ list]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 6}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1,
>      3, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1, 6}, {1, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3) and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
SequenceReplace[#, x : {a_, 0 ..} :> Splice[x /. 0 :> a]] & /@ PadRight[list]
```

{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 6}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1,
3, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
l = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1, 6}, {1, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2}};
```

Another way using `Table` and `Insert`:

```
s = Max@(Length /@ list);

With[{size = s}, Insert[#, Splice@Table[Last@#, size - Length@#], -1] & /@ l]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 6, 6}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 2}}`